# Output value: A_CONSTANT . ' concatenated to a string' from YAML Vagrant config

Tags: php, wordpress, yaml, vagrant, vvv-wordpress

When provisioning a new wordpress instance using the [VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV) project I can configure constants that will be included in the wp-config.php like so:

```
  wpconfig_constants:
    WP_DEBUG: true
    WP_DEBUG_LOG: true
```

I am attempting to configure:

```
WP_CONTENT_DIR:  "ABSPATH . \"myob/wp-content\""
WP_CONTENT_URL:  DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE . "myob/wp-content"
```

Every combination of commenting/quotes tried so far ends up being invalid yaml or outputs something like:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', 'ABSPATH . "myob/wp-content"' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE . "myob/wp-content"' );
```

VVV is very considerate and attempts to create the wp-content path configured like so `/ABSPATH . "myob/wp-content/`

I would like VVV to configure the constants like this:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . 'myob/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE . 'myob/wp-content' );
```